# g:link ignoring named mapping

Tags: grails, gsp

I have the following named `UrlMapping`

```
name 'admin_user' :"/admin/user/$action?/$id?"(controller:'userAdmin')
```

On a different page `site/edit.gsp (/admin/site/edit)` I am calling:

```
<g:link  mapping="admin_user" action='create' class="create" >New User</g:link>
```

But its generating

```
/admin/site/create
```

basically ignoring my mapping parameter.  Any help on what I a doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally got down to the bottom of this it was an issue with two url mappings that conflicted.

```
name 'admin_user' :"/admin/user/$action?/$id?"(controller:'userAdmin')
"/$controller/$action?/$id?"()
```

It was ignoring the first and always using the second.  I eventually had to just abandon using  the admin prefix and actually go with `/admin/userAdmin/` I defined

```
"/admin/$controller/$action?/$id?"()
```

And then used createLink with controller='userAdmin'.

Whenever I needed a link to /user/xxx I explicitly defined it.

Big pain in the arse....

Answer (score 0):

This mapping seems to be OK. I got it right in my Grails v2.0.4 environment.

```
<g:link  mapping="admin_user" action='create' class="create" >New User</g:link>
```

produces a link to:

```
/admin/user/create
```

and

```
<g:link  mapping="admin_user" action='create' class="create" id="3">New User</g:link>
```

generates

```
/admin/user/create/3
```

You may check if the UrlMapping.groovy is in the right place, or the docs of the Grails version you adopt.

Comment: Where was the .gsp you ran this in ?

Comment: It doesn't matter because you can use g:link everywhere. I've tried in '/' or `/path/`. Both path is fine.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you aren't creating or using your named mapping correctly. You're trying to use both a named mapping and an `action`, but the action form is taking precedence, which is why you end up with a link to `/controller/action`. Based on the [docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#namedMappings), you need to have a specific named mapping for your action, which looks more like this:

```
name createAdminUser: "/admin/user/create" {
    controller = 'userAdmin'
}
```

You can still pass named parameters like `$id?` (which doesn't seem to make sense for a create) via `params="[name: value]"`.
Use it in your view like:

```
<g:link mapping="createAdminUser" class="create">New User</g:link>
```

Comment: Which part is in correct?  The closure, or the name ?  Or the fact I am using parameters like $action?

Comment: The closure combined with the `g:link` tag using `action`